# Citing other forums (eg reddit, MAL, etc) in answers

Tags: discussion, references

In my answer here [Why does the quintuplets' father hate Fuutarou?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66969/why-does-the-quintuplets-father-hate-fuutarou), кяαzєя♦ says

> Please stop linking to your own reddit post without proper disclosure. If you want to quote a certain section, please quote that relevant portion and not just have a link to some post where there is a comment without a proper citation. Explain how things are relevant rather than say it is a certain why because some rando on the internet said so. – кяαzєя♦

I flagged that comment after editing accordingly 'I already finished editing – BCLC' and then I was 'declined' (no explanation).

In my question here [Why does Yor call Anya as Anya-san instead of Anya-chan?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/67013/why-does-yor-call-anya-as-anya-san-instead-of-anya-chan) Fumikage Tokoyami answers citing a reddit post [Why does Yor say Anya-san instead of Anya-chan? - Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/SpyxFamily/comments/undj6f/why_does_yor_say_anyasan_instead_of_anyachan/)

I flagged 'are you allowed to just CITE reddit?' and then I was declined with the ff explanation (a typical template) :

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention

What is going on? What is the difference between Fumikage Tokoyami's citation and my previous citation?

Comment: Reddit and other forums are tertiary sources, like online wikis are far from the original source and can be outdated, incomplete, or incorrect/inaccurate in it's interpretation of the information in question. This unreliable. None the less we understand the level effort to properly cite information can be a bit toilsome for users of a recreational Q&A site, so at times we cut users some slack if the sources are somewhat relevant. But yours in the case cited falls short.

Answer (score 7):

**You're conflicting "paraphrasing" with "quoting".**

First, let's take a look at [your revision](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/66970/4) and the part which was removed.

> 3. As for Fuutarou's dad and the quints' dad, see these
>
> [Do Itsuki or Miku (or the other quints?) ask their dad why their tutor Fuutarou is a student in their own school and year level?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66528/do-itsuki-or-miku-or-the-other-quints-ask-their-dad-why-their-tutor-fuutarou)
>
> <s>and</s>
>
> [Looking for a tutor for my daughters who transferred schools because they failed so miserably. I'm willing to pay 5 times the market price. Who do you think I should get: someone in their year? Or, oh idk, someone with a bachelor's degree? Or even just a high/secondary school diploma?](https://www.reddit.com/r/5ToubunNoHanayome/comments/t3ljon/looking_for_a_tutor_for_my_daughters_who/)
>
> - some of which spoils a little of Vol1 manga that cut was in the anime and some spoils parts of the manga equivalent of after s2 i.e. manga equivalent of the movie.

Leaving aside the other issue about non-disclosure of self-thread, *there was no explanation of what should the reader find in the Reddit thread*. An external link on its own is *not enough*. At the very least, it also needs either a) direct quotations from specific replies, or b) paraphrased contents. Neither was done in this case.

---

For [Fumikage's original revision](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/67014/1), I have checked a few times, and I couldn't find any direct quotations/copy-paste (i.e. plagiarism). Instead, I observed that the Reddit thread was used *as the source for the idea*, and then they used *their own words* (i.e. paraphrased) to refine the idea further. This is a valid approach, and [even encouraged by Stack Exchange](https://anime.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).